# Dynamically change text with a lot of partial views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Sorry for the title it might sound like a noob question, but i really dont know any kinda javascript.

let me explane a lot more. I'm trying to make a reputation system. So i have a button up and down, and number in the middle. So when the user presses the button it sould disable the button, and add or remove 1 from the number.

Now changing the number is basic i can find that anywhere but everone tells me to use a id. but i cant use a id because it wont be unique since i use this code mulityple times, and i dont know how many times. 
This is the code for the buttons

```
<div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MessageReputationUp", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id })';return false;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                </button>
                <div> <text id="ReputationCount" style="padding-left:2px;">&nbsp; @Model.Reputation.ToString()</text></div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-link reputation-buttons" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MessageReputationDown", "Forum", new { groupId = Model.GroupId, threadId = Model.ThreadId, messageId = Model.Id })';return false;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

So the text where id = reputation counter need to change when i press up. Now it get a little bit more complicated. The button need to disable once i pressed it but when you press down the button needs to be renabled. But that i can figur own if i can see a basic example of takeling this problem.

Comment: You can use the id attribute on a single element, but you can use it in your code as many times as you'd like.

Comment: I made you a sample on Codepen https://codepen.io/android5803/pen/gxBmVp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [javascript classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Classes act sort of like ids, but for N elements.

1. Wrap each voting structure within a div.
2. When upvoting/downvoting, get the current text of the inner div, transform it to an integer, add or substract 1 and change the text with the updated value. You can enable/disable the buttons or whatever you want to do.

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.votes_manager', function() {
       var elem = $(this).parent().children('.displayer');
       var value = parseInt(elem.text());
       if ($(this).hasClass('increase')) {
         ++value;
       }
       else {
         --value;
       }
       elem.text(value);
   });
   ```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzjqw5cg/1/).

PS: this solution uses [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com).